# Unable to update Table using sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, model, sequelize.js

I am unable to update row using sequelize. It seems like it's skipping the query because no logs are generated in the terminal when updating. Other operations like insert and destroy are working fine.

**UPDATE CODE**

```
const uuid = require('uuid/v4');

const db = require('../../models');

const TempToken = db.tempTokens;

exports.generateToken = async (req) =>{
  'use strict';
  const token = uuid();
  // let  transaction = await db.sequelize.transaction();
  try{

    console.log(req.userId);  /////////// DATA prints in console
    console.log(req.device.type);  /////////// DATA prints in console

    const insert = {
      user: req.userId,
      device: req.device.type,
    };

    await TempToken.update({valid: false}, {where:{id: 9 } });

    insert['token'] = token;
    insert['deviceConfig'] = JSON.stringify(req.device);
    await TempToken.create(insert);

    return token;
  }
  catch (e){
    return e;
  }
};
```

TempTokens model -

```
/* jshint indent: 2 */

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('tempTokens', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    user: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(225),
      allowNull: true,
    },
    token: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(225),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    device: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(225),
      allowNull: true,
    },
    deviceConfig: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    valid: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      default: true,
    },
  }, {
    tableName: 'tempTokens',
  });
};
```

Data in `req.userId` and `req.device.type` are valid. And, `id:9` is also valid and present in table.

Terminal log is -

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `tempTokens` (`id`,`user`,`token`,`device`,`deviceConfig`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?,?);
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be defaultValue not default:

```
valid: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: true,
    }
```